# deleted post few minutes ago

Tags: discussion

I'm new on this community. I tried to leave a comment a few minutes ago on the page "[section numbering in 'tufte-book'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301362/section-numbering-in-tufte-book)", but i accidentally post an "answer".

The given MWE uses `tufte-book`. I suspect that `tufte-book` uses the package `titlesec`. The most recent version of `titlesec`, which is a week old, causes the same error.

On "[Formatting subsections and chapters in tufte-book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96090/formatting-subsections-and-chapters-in-tufte-book)" is stated "...The tufte documentclass loads the titlesec package..."

So this makes me believe that `titlesec` is the cause of the problem, even if this package isn't visible in the shown MWE.

I wasn't able to rectify my post, because it was deleted. I now have to have 50 point, but i don't know how to get them.

Kind regards,

Richard

Comment: I doubt posting a new question is the right way either, but I will give you a +1 for earnest effort.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: here's a response in a comment that appeared with what you posted: " It's true that `titlesec` had a small bug, but this was fixed, but the O.P. is not using `titlesec` according to the MWE, so this is not related."  so really, a new question is in order, which is this one.  `tufte-book` does not use `titlesec`, so for that to be relevant, it would have to be included with `usepackage`.

Comment: I thougth I was sending a message to Christian Hupfer, because I clicked on his name. But apparently it become some kind of post.

Comment: I am willing to check with the older version of `titlesec` before it was updated some days ago.

Comment: I'm using Miktex and Texmaker. I would like to know how to install an older version of titlesec, because the latest version gives me problems. That's what led me to this site.

Comment: Oh my, the newer `titlesec`version from 2016/03/21 is working, apparently there was an intermediate version with some bug that was published some days earlier (2016/03/16) has the bug and the section numbers are vanishing in the document body (but not in the ToC)

Comment: @Richard: I am sorry, it was a fault to delete your answer, you're right, most likely! I've voted to undelete your answer

Comment: Ok, no problem. But i'm still curious, how do you download and install a version of a package, which is not the latest version?

Comment: @Richard -- i have to retract my earlier comment that `tufte-book` doesn't use `titlesec`.  it doesn't load it directly, but one of the subsidiary packages it calls does load it.

Comment: @Richard: I'm using TeXLive and by default, during updates, there's a backup of the old package version. I've just placed the contents of the old version in a local directory and compiled the example from the other question. The version is from 2016/03/15 -- that's the buggy one (whatever the bug is, right now), the one from `2016/21/03` is working fine

Comment: Ow, isee. I have version 2.10.1 installed (2.10.2 is the latest version). So i have most probably the faulty version of 2016/03/15.

Comment: Maybe George, the guy which posted the question at "http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301362/section-numbering-in-tufte-book" also has version 2.10.1 installed. Which gives him the same problem.

Comment: Because Barbara confirmed that tufte-book uses titlesec

Comment: @Richard Note that she's barbara in this case, not Barbara ;-)